# How to setState a nested object from API to a new object

Tags: reactjs

I know this issue answered few times here but I couldn't find the specific solution I'm looking for.

I get throw axios a response of a nested object. I try to setState it to a new Object in a way that I could use it in an effective way when the page will render, but the new object won't change for some reason and will stay an empty array.

Now, my purpose is when I using the stats object in the render, I will have access to every attribute in this object

```
import "../App.css";
import axios from "axios";

class home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      platform: null,
      gamertag: null,
      stats: []
    };
  }

  showStats = (plat, tag) => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/${plat}/${tag}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats);
        this.setState({
          stats: [...response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats]
        });
      })

      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Insert Platform"
          id="inputSmall"
          onChange={e => this.setState({ platform: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Insert Gamertag"
          id="inputSmall"
          onChange={e => this.setState({ gamertag: e.target.value })}
        />

        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          onClick={() =>
            this.showStats(this.state.platform, this.state.gamertag)
          }
        />
        <div>{this.state.stats}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default home;
```

[response and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRqad.png)

Comment: do you get the console log executed ? or the catch block ? any errors ?

Comment: the console.log get the api request just fine, i can post the response if it's helps

Comment: yes that would help. Coz, when the state is successfully set, the you should get errors like `cannot render object with keys` when `this.state.stats` is rendered inside the div.

Comment: response added...

Comment: you get the error right there in the image you have posted. `gameModeStats` is an `object`. But you are trying to spread it like an array. `stats` is an array in your state and while you are trying to spread it, you are doing it inside an `array`

Comment: it looks like your ````response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats```` isn't an array,  can you put a ````typeof ```` to check what type of data it is? ````console.log(typeof response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats)````

Comment: as far as i know this how it should do, cause even if i put null instead react will fix it as an array, because it try to render a collection of children

Comment: it's an object.

Comment: @GilNuriel An object isnt iterable, so thats your issue, maybe try to iterate through the keys and map them to the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is an object you will not be able to destructuring then as an array. 
Maybe try this:

```
  showStats = (plat, tag) => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/${plat}/${tag}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats);
        //Map the arrays based on their keys
        let arrayStats = Object.keys( response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats )
                       .map( statKey => response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats[statKey] );
        this.setState({ stats: arrayStats});
      })

      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

Comment: An off topic question but why would you use axios when you can use the simple awesome fetch api included?

Comment: now it just saying  the Object is not valid as a react child and i should use an array instead

Comment: @GilNuriel Yep thats beacuse the items inside the array are the objects that you want to render, maybe use a map or somethin to render them correctly: Check this codeSanbox, ive tried to replicate your issue with mockedData: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-wildflower-v5fd8

Answer (score 0):

problem fix:

**before:**

`{duo: {…}, duo-fpp: {…}, solo: {…}, solo-fpp: {…}, squad: {…}, …}`

```
let arr = [response.data.data.attributes.gameModeStats],
          stats = arr.map(Object.values);
        this.setState({ stats });
        console.log(this.state.stats[0]);
```

**after:**

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```